# use google translate premium API by json

Tags: python, json, google-translate

I am new to google translate api premium edition and json. I have the service account and the key credentials save in a json file. I want to use the 'nmt' model. The following are my python code. I can get the access token but still cannot make it run correctly. Please let me know which part I did wrong. I appreciate your help.

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

base_url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2']

# load json credential keys
my_credentials = GoogleCredentials.from_stream('./data/TranslateAPI-cbe083d405fe.json')

# get access token 
access_token = my_credentials.get_access_token(base_url)

# build service
service = build('translate', 'v2', credentials=access_token, model='nmt')

text = u'So let us begin anew--remembering on both sides that civility is not a sign of weakness, and sincerity is always subject to proof. Let us nevernegotiate out of fear. But let us never fear to negotiate.'
test = service.translations().list(q=text, target='es')
results = test.execute()
```

I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ying\workspace\GoogleTranslateAPI_v3\test1.py", line 32, in <module>
test = service.translations().list(q=text, target='es')
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 778, in method
headers, params, query, body = model.request(headers,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Google Cloud Translate Client](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/translate-client.html)
The client you are using doesn't support "NMT". The error you got in this case is about you entered wrong type of value to "model" parameter. The correct value should be a [googleapiclient.Model](https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.model.Model-class.html)